# Why are my BigQuery streaming inserts being rate limited?

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm getting `403 rateLimitExceeded` errors while doing streaming inserts into BigQuery.  I'm doing many streaming inserts in parallel, so while I understand that this might be cause for some rate limiting, I'm not sure what rate limit in particular is the issue.

Here's what I get:

`{
  "code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Exceeded rate limits: Your table exceeded quota for rows. For more information, see https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/troubleshooting-errors",
    "reason" : "rateLimitExceeded"
  } ],
  "message" : "Exceeded rate limits: Your table exceeded quota for rows. For more information, see https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/troubleshooting-errors"
}`

Based on [BigQuery's troubleshooting docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/troubleshooting-errors), `403 rateLimitExceeded` is caused by either [concurrent rate limiting](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quota-policy#queries) or [API request limits](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quota-policy#apirequests), but the docs make it sound like neither of those apply to streaming operations.

However, the `message` in the error mentions `table exceeded quota for rows`, which sounds more like the `403 quotaExceeded` error.  The [streaming quotas](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quota-policy#streaminginserts) are:

- Maximum row size: 1 MB - *I'm under this - my average row size is in the KB and I specifically limit sizes to ensure they don't hit 1MB*
- HTTP request size limit: 10 MB - *I'm under this - my average batch size is < 400KB and max is < 1MB*
- Maximum rows per second: 100,000 rows per second, per table. Exceeding this amount will cause quota_exceeded errors. *- can't imagine I'd be over this - each batch is about 500 rows, and each batch takes about 500 milliseconds.  I'm running in parallel but inserting across about 2,000 tables, so while it's possible (though unlikely) that I'm doing 100k rows/second, there's no way that's per table (more like 1,000 rows/sec per table max)*
- Maximum rows per request: 500 - *I'm right at 500*
- Maximum bytes per second: 100 MB per second, per table. Exceeding this amount will cause quota_exceeded errors.  - *Again, my insert rates are not anywhere near this volume by table.*

Any thoughts/suggestions as to what this rate limiting is would be appreciated!

Comment: If you can provide your project/tables, we can look in detail at what might be happening... That error is specific to the 100k rows/s/ table limit, and shouldn't be triggered if you're streaming at the O(1000/s) rate.

Comment: As at August 2019, 100000 rows per second also applies across the whole project. So if your 2000 tables are in the same project and you do 50 inserts per second on average for each of them..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you are occasionally submitting more than 100,000 rows per second to a single table. Might your parallel insert processes occasionally all line up on the same table?

The reason this is reported as a rate limit error is to give a push-back signal to slow down: to handle sporadic spikes of operations on a single table, you can back off and try again to spread the load out.

This is different from a quota failure which implies that retrying will still fail until the quota epoch rolls over (for ex, daily quota limits).

Comment: Upon further investigation after prompting here, it looks like I was indeed hitting the 100k rows/sec limit on a single table.  I'm using a modified version of BigQueryTableInserter (from https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK), which I didn't realize used a pool of 100 threads for inserts - so each of my Spark executors were doing up to 100 inserts at once (each has its own JVM), which could easily get in the neighborhood of 100K rows/sec/table.  In the end I just shrunk the size of that thread pool and the error is gone.  I'm using an expo back off as well, just in case.

Comment: Said that, when I receive 403 error with 'rateLimitExceeded' reason I can see that the job inserted the rows. Now, in a batch load scenario, I don't know if I have to rollback for this error or not and the documentation is not very clear. My default action is to retry and then I have duplications in Bigquery which I'd like to avoid. Any suggestion?