# GBQ streaming inserts: What is user_method quota?

Tags: google-bigquery

We got this error a lot when doing streaming insert to GBQ

```
Exceeded rate limits: Your user_method exceeded quota for api requests per user per method. For more information, see https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/troubleshooting-errors [403]
```

From what I can read from the following page, there's no "per user" limit applying for streaming insert.

> https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas

Could someone help me to understand what is this quota about and where could we config it. Thanks!

Comment: check if you see something odd on the Iam & Admin -> Quotes page, maybe something is triggering from there https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/quotas

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33304545/why-are-my-bigquery-streaming-inserts-being-rate-limited

Comment: @Pentium10 guess the quota have been refreshed so I couldn't see any odds there. will try later. thanks!

Comment: @GrahamPolley that doesn't help cause it was a different type of quota exceeded than mine.